# jquery: adding class to <a> or <li> from value

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class to each `<a>` or `<li>` that is the same value as `$(this).val()` in the code.

```
  options.each(function(){
     $("#target dd ul").append('<li><a href="#">' +
       $(this).text() + '<span class="value">' +
       $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>');
  });
```

I am thankful for any hints!

Comment: Do you mean all of `<a>/<li>` or just `<a>/<li>` under `$("#target dd ul")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a:contains('+ $(this).val()+')').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: for `a` and `li` too: `$('a:contains('+ $(this).val()+'), li:contains('+ $(this).val()+')').addClass('newClass');`

Comment: @netdjw: Or `$("a, li").filter(":contains(...)")`. But this solution is icky anyway, because the `.val()` value needs proper escaping inside a selector.

Comment: Thanks! I took your idea and changed it to: `$("#target dd ul").append('<li><a class="'+ $(this).val()+'" href="#">' +`